# Accessing a sharepoint 2013 online list from a stand-alone angular 2 application

Tags: angular, sharepoint, cors

I'm trying to use the REST Sharepoint API with an HTTP call inside an Angular 2 application. This app will be deployed as a stand-alone app using Ionic framework. I'm facing CORS issues when calling my list hosted in a sharepoint site.
Is it possibile to enable CORS on sharepoint? Or how can I solve my issue?
Note: in my scenario I do not have Azure AD.

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Angular 2 app as office 365 app, so you could use ADAL library to authenticate your request to SharePoint online and access list data.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/12/16/angular-2-0-and-the-microsoft-graph/

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can enable CORS in SharePoint. You can use the web.config to allow a single external domain or if you need to allow more, you can write an HttpModule and install that into the web.config. Certainly achievable. If you want to make things even easier and avoid CORS altogether, deploy your compiled Angular app into the SiteAssets library on SharePoint itself. This is how I do it.

For accessing SharePoint lists, use the @pnp/sp libraries.